# Does AppStore Provisioining Profile need to be regenerated for push notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I generated my Appstore provisioining profile before setting my App Id to have Push Notification enabled.  I then edited my App Id to enable push notification.

Does my AppStore Provisioining Profile need to be regenerated for push notification before I submit?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you need to regenerate provisioning profile.